# Display and save '\0' in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

.Net 4.5 Framework.
I have a string:

```
string input = "abcdqw\0asdv\0aaa";
```

Is there any way to display the string in a richtextbox like

> abcdqwasdvaaa

and when I save it to a .txt file then open by notepad++, it is

> abcdqw[nul]asdv[nul]aaa

???

When I display it in a normal way as

```
richTextBox.Text = input;
```

the output is just

> abcdqw

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mjwills when I display it in a normal way as `richTextBox.Text = input`, the output is just "abcdqw"

Comment: Google for `richtextbox display null characters c#`.

Comment: Thanks for your advance. I've tried to google this but haven't found the answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a RichTextBox load a file that has ASCII nul's in it:

```
yourRichTextBox.LoadFile(@"C:\path\to\file\with\nulls.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

[image]

But you can't do it by setting its text property. I presume this is because that (ultimately) is managed via windows message calls (WM_SETTEXT)which will cut off at the first ascii nul encountered

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand. But do you know why in VB6, the nul character can be shown on richtextbox? I've tried the VB6 code with the same purpose in WinXP and Win10. In WinXP, richtextbox displays 'nul' as space; in Win10, the 'nul' is shown as  an empty character. When I save the text from richtextboxes to a .txt file, it still shows the 'nul'.

Comment: Did some more research and today's been a learning day for me too!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried a null character in a `RichTextBox`, however I guess you are getting a truncated string on display. If that is the case, the solution should be as easy as

```
var input = "abcdqw\0asdv\0aaa";
var displayResult = input.Replace("\0","");
```

Comment: I've tried this bute when saving, I lost the '\0' in text file.

Comment: @N.H.Tung save the original, not the modified version?

Comment: @N.H.Tung are you modifying this in the UI? Is that why you cant save the original?

Answer (score 0):

`\0` is a "null character".

It seems rich textbox is truncating the string at `\0`, use like this

```cs
string input = "abcdqw\0asdv\0aaa";
var cleaned = input.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
richTextBox.Text = cleaned;
```